# Testing UK carbon monoxide power socket is live

Tags: mains, multimeter

My [Deta 1121 carbon monoxide detector](http://www.detaelectrical.co.uk/images/downloads/products/safety_alarms/Instructions/INS0049_-_CO_Alarm.pdf) is showing no lights. I'd like to test the ceiling socket to determine if the fault is with the wiring or with the detector.

[image]

A separate heat detector is on the same RCB circuit and powered on, so I'm hopeful it's just the CO detector that needs replacing.

I have an earlier version of the [Silverline 513121 multimeter](https://www.silverlinetools.com/en-GB/Product/ProductDetail?MainCategory=Elettricit%C3%A0&ModelName=513121) and believe these are the correct settings to use when testing UK mains electricity:
[image: multi meter settings for mains checks]

My plan to test if the circuit is live is to:

1. Set the Multimeter to 600V AC ~
2. Place the black probe on the Neutral (grey wire) screw
3. Place the red probe on the Live (brown wire) screw

Could anyone please confirm that sounds sensible?

Comment: This isn't an electronics design question. I'll request migration to DIY.

Comment: @Transistor - apologies and thank you

Comment: @jamesT - yes, your idea is sensible. If you get around 110 V, that means wiring and voltage are OK. (check on the bottom level screws so that you are directly probing the wires that go into the sensor)

Comment: @Whiskeyjack OP mentioned that they are in the UK, so around 240 V would be the correct voltage.

Comment: Sorry guys, I mixed up US and UK. For UK you should expect 220-240 VAC.

Comment: Nicely presented question! Yes, suggested method is good.

Comment: I agree, this is a very nicely written question.

Comment: *you need a [CAT III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measurement_category#Cat_II) meter to measure on this location of the installation. This one is only CAT II.

Comment: @Jeroen3 isn’t Cat III  for industrial busbars and Cat II for residential Busbars?

Comment: I would remove Sensor and ohm out LN and expect a stepdown primary winding resistance

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 busbars and breaker panel are CAT IV.

Comment: @JamesT your post is a textbook example of a well presented question .... since you appear to be a novice with using a multimeter, a word of caution ... when one probe is connected to a potentially dangerous circuit, **do not touch the tip of the other probe**

Comment: TY @Jeroen3 understood, but for residential outlets  is that still the case after line loss and breaker protection?  I have seen arc flashes on 120Vac 1m from the panel and a short will sputter 1cm copper particles from screwdriver tips onto safety glasses quite well

Comment: 1cm thick screwdriver with blade and sputter 1u particles 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just done the test as outlined:

1. Set the Multimeter to 600V AC ~
2. Place the black probe on the Neutral (grey wire) screw
3. Place the rede probe on the Live (brown wire) screw

And got a reading of 243V on the multi-meter. Thanks for the feedback in the comments.

Comment: The irony is after all that the Deta 1121 is now no longer available to buy so I can't just swap in a new one. :)

Comment: Ah! It looks like the BRK CO850MBXi has a compatible base.